# How to add an Integer in Arraylist<? extends Number>?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, numbers, wildcard

I'm trying to add an Integer to an Arraylist with a wildcard that extends Number Class. The compiler gives me an error. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WildCard {
    ArrayList<? extends Number> an;

    public WildCard() {
        an = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void addI(Integer a) {
        an.add(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WildCard w = new WildCard();
        Integer b = 3;
        w.addI(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Impossible.

That's what wildcard means.

You're asking: "How do I find the corner in this circle?" - or "How do I move an immovable object?"

wildcard *means*: Cannot be added to.

The reason it means that, is highlighted by this simple exercise:

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<? extends Number> whoknows = doubles;
whoknows.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
```

note that `whoknows` and `doubles` are pointing to the exact same list. There is only one list here; whatever you do with the `doubles` list is also done to `whoknows` and vice versa.

Soooo, if you find any way at all to add an integer to this, you... just... added an integer. To a list of doubles. uhoh.

Which is why you can't.

Comment: I disagree with the statement "wildcard *means*: Cannot be added to" It is absolutely possible to add elements to a `List<? super T>`, i.e., when you have a wildcard with a lower bound. Rather than that, you should explain that it is some type that you do not know about. It's more of "there's an `ArrayList<T>` where T is *some type* that extends `Number`"

Comment: The `? extends` wildcard means 'cannot be added to'. The `? super` wildcard means the reverse. The answer is complex enough as is; an SO answer is properly not the right place for a complete and in-depth treatise on co/contra/and invariance, and how java has implemented these concepts. At least, not unless the SO question is literally 'please explain these concepts to me'.

Comment: Oh, no, I didn't mean that you should've explained variances in this answer and all that. The example you've given is great and is probably all you needed - I was just being nitpicky about the meaning of `?`

Answer (score 0):

Change wildcard `?` to `T`:

```
public class Test <T extends Number> {
    ArrayList<T> an;

    public Test(){
        an = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void addI(T a){
        an.add(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Test<Number> w = new Test<>();
        Integer b = 3;
        w.addI(b);

        Test<Integer> w2 = new Test<>();
        Integer b2 = 32;
        w2.addI(b2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do it like this and you can add Integer.

```
ArrayList<Number> an;
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> an
```

Comment: I need to use Wildcard in the exercise